# Mouse is offset only in one particular GUI in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 3 different GUI containers/sections, one for showing resources, one for building, and one for inventory. Clicking anything in the resource and building sections works completely fine, the mouse is where it needs to be and clicking/hovering over a button will actually click/hover over the button.

The problem is only in the inventory GUI. I'm not sure how it's any different, so I don't know what I need to provide here for anyone to help me out, so please ask me for any extra info if you need it in the comments. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the code or the UI elements, or whatever else it might be. I'm going to provide some examples of this happening, though.

Here is a gif of what it looks like in the inventory (ignore the items not doing what they are supposed to): https://s3.gifyu.com/images/ezgif.com-gif-maker-37b00e5b2a1c164b2.gif

Here is a gift of me just hovering/clicking around in the inventory: https://s3.gifyu.com/images/ezgif.com-gif-maker97b27b8783d784c6.gif

Here is a gif of this working in the "Building" section: https://s9.gifyu.com/images/ezgif.com-gif-maker-287d7a9723f9db2b1.gif

Here is a gif of this working in the "Resources" section: https://s3.gifyu.com/images/ezgif.com-gif-maker-18662e4229ebd27a2.gif

Here are some images that might be useful. Here is the layout:

[image]

There is no difference when I select, for example, Building and Inventory. Here is a comparison:[image]

[image]

I have looked around on Google for about 30 minutes, but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. The issue was with the slot prefab that was in the inventory screen, as it had text that was way bigger than it was: https://prnt.sc/uDRXz2Kr4kQr

I initially hadn't noticed this as simply clicking on the prefab itself shows that it's the right size: https://prnt.sc/BXQqAzMD-kWX

Resizing the text seems to fix the issue.